# How to take log while running app in emulator through comand line

Tags: android

I am running my app in emulator through command line referring [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html) link. But i am not able to find any command through which i can take log of the app running on emulator.

Comment: did I answer your question?

Comment: yes.. sorry i didn't get time to accept the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Command to receive the log buffers on commandline is:

```
[adb] logcat [<option>] ... [<filter-spec>] ...
```

There are several options that can be passed that can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html).

For more informations continue reading here:

- [Logcat Documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html)
- [Reading and Writing Logs](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html)